# Group dataframe according to start and stop columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to cut/group a pandas Dataframe according to a start and a stop column, but only in the case of start->stop.

I would like the range of indexes from 'start' non-zero value to 'stop' non-zero value. But only if the 'start' non-zero value is followed next by a 'stop' non-zero value. Running through the indices from top to bottom

I attached some code creating a simplified version of the problem and a corresponding image.

```
col1 = np.zeros(10)
col2 = np.zeros(10)
col1[[0, 1, 5, 8]] = 1
col2[[3, 6, 7, 9]] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': col1, 'stop': col2})
```

[image: Example Dataframe]

The desired output would group the indexes somewhat like:
[(1,2,3), (5,6), (8,9)]

Additional info in case this would simplify things:

1. Merging the columns would be fine.
2. My original data frame has a pd.TimedeltaIndex.

Visual Clarification of the desired result:
[image: Visual Clarification]

Comment: So, you need delta btw the columns, right? Why don't you just substract one column from another and store it as a new col? - Then you can filter out the values that `!=0`

Comment: I don't need the (time) delta between the rows, but the specific rows range - to either label them with something like session numbers 0,1,2,3,... or directly group them for computation (grouper/cut etc) for groupby.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the requirements, it shell be a range from first `start` non-zero value to first `stop` non-zero value, shan't it be?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. I would like the range of indexes from 'start' non-zero value to 'stop' non-zero value. But only if the  'start' non-zero value is followed next by a 'stop' non-zero value. Running through the indices from top to bottom.

Comment: I added a visual clarification of what I'd like to achieve. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to look the intervals of `start` and `stop` and find out which are “valid” interval ends:

```
>>> ends = df.index.to_series().where(df['stop'].ne(0))
>>> starts = df.index.to_series().where(df['start'].ne(0))
>>> ends
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    6.0
7    7.0
8    NaN
9    9.0
dtype: float64
>>> starts
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    5.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    8.0
9    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Now we can try to get for each valid start the next valid end:

```
>>> next_end = ends.bfill().rename('end')
>>> valid_starts = starts.dropna().rename('start')
>>> candidates = valid_starts.to_frame().join(next_end, how='left')
>>> candidates
   start  end
0    0.0  3.0
1    1.0  3.0
5    5.0  6.0
8    8.0  9.0
```

Here we see that there is an issue with the interval starting at 0: another interval starts later (at 1) so [0, 3] is not valid and we should only keep [1, 3]. This could be done with groupby + max for example:

```
>>> intervals = candidates.groupby('end')['start'].max().reset_index().astype(int)
>>> intervals
   end  start
0    3      1
1    6      5
2    9      8
```

Finally generating the list of indexes from the endpoints is easy:

```
>>> intervals.agg(lambda s: list(range(s['start'], s['end'] + 1)), axis='columns')
0    [1, 2, 3]
1       [5, 6]
2       [8, 9]
dtype: object
```